why does safari asks for permission for using microphone on every page load?
I am working with a react web view with Flutter for Mac and it uses the user's microphone.
The react app opens in Safari.
But it requests for microphone permission on every page load!
Is there any way to permanently allow microphone access for the user?
some important context:
The user cannot open settings in the web view
The user cannot access the browser's console

that's just the way safari is. the user can test the flag

This issue was solved by checking the webview's WKUIDelegate method. Under this delegate method "decideMediaCapturePermissionsFor", this method is used for show/hide popups based on the flag.
By checking this the web view doesn't ask for permissions again and again and persists permission given to the application.
the web view used was: flutter_macos_webview
